# How to use hasOne relationship correctly?

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning Laravel and I'm trying to create simple online store.
I created tables Items and Amounts. Now I want to display all Items with their  amount in stock but for some reason unknown to me, amount of item is not fetched into items.

These are my schemas for tables:
**Items:**

```
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('name', 120)->nullable(false);
                $table->float('price',8,2)->unsigned()->nullable(false);
                $table->longText('short_specification');
                $table->longText('specification');
                $table->longText('description');
                $table->string('photo', 100);
                $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

                $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            });
```

**Amounts:**

```
    Schema::create('amounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('amount')->unsigned()->nullable(false);
                $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            });

            Schema::table('amounts',function($table){
                $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items');
                $table->primary('item_id');
            });
```

These are my models:
**Item:**

```
    class Item extends Model
    {
        public $timestamps = false;


        function amount()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Amount','item_id','id');
        }
    }
```

**Amount:**

```
    class Amount extends Model
    {

        function item()
        {
                 //$this->belongsTo('App\Item');
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Item','item_id','id');
        }
    }
```

When I do:

```
$items = DB::table('items')->get();
dd($items);
return view('home')->with('items',$items);
```

Items are displayed correctly, but amount of item isn't there.
When I do:

```
    @foreach($items as $item)

            {{ $item->id }}
            {{ $item->amount }}

    @endforeach
```

I get:

> *Undefined property: stdClass::$amount (View: D:\2.
>   PROGRAMY\xampp\htdocs\silicon_store\resources\views\home.blade.php)*
>   error.

From what I've seen on the web (I've been trying to fix this for over 3 hours now so I must be doing something totally wrong) it should work properly but it isn't.

Comment: The parameters of the `belongsTo` relation seem wrong. The foreign key `item_id` should be the second parameter. The parent's key `id` the third.

Comment: You are right, is should be `$this->belongsTo('App\Item','item_id','id')` although because of the fact that a column in Amounts table is named `user_id` Laravel is looking for column `id` in users table by default so `$this->belongsTo('App\Item');` will suffice.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you don't need to specify the keys. I recommend doing so as it helps new developers on the project to understand what is going on. Laravels magic is sometimes hard to grasp. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$items = DB::table('items')->get();`, you're using the query builder. It won't have the value of the relationship unless you join the amounts table in the query.

```
$items = DB::table('items')
        ->leftJoin('amounts', 'items.id', '=', 'amounts.item_id')
        ->get();
```

I think you could also use an Eloquent query. In that case each `$item` would be an instance of the `Item` model rather than a StdClass object.

```
$items = App\Item::with('amount')->get();
```

Comment: Both solutions are working perfectly! Although instead of `App\Item::with('amount')->get();` I have to add `use App\Item;` and then make it `Item::with('amount')->get();`Thanks for help, you made my tonight's sleep peaceful!

Answer (score 0):

or you can use kind of this query

```php
$items = App\Item::whereHas('amount')->get()
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) link to understanding `whereHas`

Comment: I was just about to post another question concerning using pagination with: `Item::with(['amount'])->where('amount.amount', '>', 0)` and `Item::whereHas('amount', function($query)
        {
            $query->where('amount','>',0);
        });` worked like a charm! Thanks!